# Pandas: change values to NA if index and column are the same

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe and want to change values to NA if index and column names are the same. Is there an elegant way to achieve this? I can only think of a tedious solution with apply and function.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1], 'b': [1, 1], 'c': [1, 1]})
df.index = ['a', 'b']
df
+---+---+---+---+
|   | a | b | c |
+---+---+---+---+
| a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| b | 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

To

```
+---+-----+-----+---+
|   | a   | b   | c |
+---+-----+-----+---+
| a |None | 1   | 1 |
| b | 1   |None | 1 |
+---+-----+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could drop down to numpy level:

```
In [32]: df.where(df.index.values[:,None] != df.columns.values)
Out[32]: 
     a    b  c
a  NaN  1.0  1
b  1.0  NaN  1
```

This works because we can take advantage of broadcasting to make an array of where index != column:

```
In [33]: df.index.values[:,None] != df.columns.values
Out[33]: 
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Wow this is very elegant! Thank you